# Регулярка на 2 условия

Tags: javascript, jquery

В общем проверяю строку на 2 условия регуляркой.
Не могу понять что не так делаю. Нужно проверить на ввод либо строки из букв либо на email.

***Подскажите почему функция отдаёт два значеия?***

```
function is_valid(login) {
  if (login.match(/^((([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([a-z0-9_\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})) | ([a-z0-9_-]{3,16}))$/gi) != null) {
    login = login.match(/^((([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([a-z0-9_\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})) | ([a-z0-9_-]{3,16}))$/gi).join('');
    return login;
  } else {
    $('#inLogin').css('border', 'red 1px solid');
    error = 2;
    return;
  }
  console.log(login);
  console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: Как минимум уберите вокруг `|` пробелы.

Comment: @Visman Спасибо))) помогло)

Comment: @visman можно немного пояснения почему пробелы вокруг `|` вызывали такое поведение?  Спасибо.

Comment: @excellproj, потому что пробел тоже символ и получалось: для emal в конце должен быть обязательно пробел, а для логина - обязательный пробел в начале. Флага `Ignore whitespace` в реулярках js нет, чтобы игнорировать пробелы.

Comment: @visman большое спасибо. Вам стоит оформить ответ)